# SocketIO server not sending data to Arduino

Tags: javascript, tcp, socket.io, arduino

I have an Arduino TCP connection that sends data to my server using socketIO. Everything works great. I'm trying to send data to tigger some events. I got `char c = client.read()` function on my Arduino sketch to listen for incoming data but unfortunately I don't receive anything.

> I'm running all my connections on one port. `HTTP/TCP` i.e my Arduino forwards data on port `3000` and my webpage also uses this port. Could this be a problem?

**server.js**

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('ON', function (data) {
    _.each(clients, function(client) {
        client.emit('ON', data);
        console.log(data + "  ON");
    });


});
socket.on('OFF', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    _.each(clients, function(client) {
        client.emit('OFF', data);
        console.log(data + "  OFF")
    });

   });
});
```

**Arduino.ino**

```
#include <dht.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

dht DHT;
#define DHT11_PIN A5


void sendData(int temperature, int humidity) ;
// Ethernet related
EthernetClient client;
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
IPAddress ip(192,168,0,11);
IPAddress server(192,168,0,10);


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    delay(3000);

  }

void loop()
{ 
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  int t = DHT.temperature;
  int h = DHT.humidity;

          // send data to the server
        sendData(t, h); 

  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print( "," );
  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print("\n");
   delay(6000);

}



void sendData(int temperature, int humidity) 
{
  if(!client.connected())
  {
    if (client.connect(server, 3000)) {
      char c = client.read();
   Serial.print(c);      

Serial.println("Sending data...");
      // send the HTTP PUT request:
      client.print("GET /weatherserver/");
      client.print(temperature);
      client.print("/");      
      client.print(humidity); 
      client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
      client.println("Host: localhost");
      client.println("User-Agent: arduino-barom");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();
      client.stop();
    } else {
       Serial.println("Could not connect.");
       client.stop();
    }
  }
  delay(6000);
}
```

Comment: you are using `char c = client.read()` on your arduino, but I really can't see `.emit` in your `server.js`, so really you're not sending anything at all. `console.log(data);` just logs the data on the `server`: are you emitting data somewhere else?

Comment: @briosheje I just updated the code to emit to client. But I'm still not getting any data. And no, I'm not emitting data somewhere else

Comment: Are you using any socket library in your arduino? Anyway, check this: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/tcp-communication-between-arduino-client-and-server and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450106/arduino-ethernet-shield-connection-to-socket-server

Comment: @briosheje thanks for the read. Not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not using socket library. I don't think I need to. I got a working example of what I aim to achieve which doesn't include the library. I think there might be something I'm missing but i'm unsure of what it is.

Comment: on your socket server, you're listening to "ON" and "OFF", try using `client.print("ON")` on your arduino, and see if something happens. Socket IO is listening to these two rulesets only, ON and OFF doesn't really refer to connect and disconnect, You should first verify that the socket is connecting (so add `console.log(socket)`on your socket callback in node, then ensure to send "ON" and "OFF" from your arduino, else nothing is meant to happen at all.

Comment: @briosheje My socket is already connected. I'm sending data on it. That works perfectly ok. The hustle is to receive data back on Arduino.

Comment: Did you try removing both the delays already? It may be that because of the 6 seconds + 6 seconds delay the request may expire. I'm just guessing anyway, I've never used socket.io to send data through http/tcp requests to arduino and vice-versa, though I suspect that if the request is being acquired by node the problem must be in arduino, the socket just emits a signal back, so if arduino is not reading that it's likely that the socket is closing the connection too early.

Comment: I strongly doubt that's the course of the problem. However I reduced the delays and nothing changed.